# There is some issue when I try to get data from mongodb by node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

This is my `index.js`. When I hit my API using postman, there is a bug in my `getdata() method` code that causes it to return the else statement rather than finding the requested resource. I'm not sure why the data targeting by ID can't be found. When I use console.log to test my code, the try statement is entered but did not find anything from the database and catch statement is returned.

```
const connectToMongo = require('./db');
var cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const photo = require('./models/photoModel');
const formidable = require('formidable');
const fs = require('fs');
const photoModel = require('./models/photoModel');

connectToMongo();
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const port = 5000;

//app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const userData = (req, res) => {
  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  console.log('1');
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, file) => {
    console.log('2');
    if (fields) {
      console.log('3');
      const { email, mno, name } = fields;
      if (!email || !mno || !name) {
        console.log('4');
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: 'Fill all the fields',
        });
      }
    }
    if (file.photo) {
      if (file.photo.size > 4000000) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: 'image size is too long',
        });
      }
      const user = new photo(fields);
      user.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(file.photo.filepath);
      user.photo.contentType = file.photo.type;

      user.save((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(400).json({
            error: 'Not save in db',
          });
        }
        console.log('above json');
        res.json(user);
      });
    }
  });
};

// The issue is here
const getdata = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log('yes');
    const photo = await photo.find({ photo: req.photo.id });
    res.json(photo);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: 'not find',
    });
  }
};

//router
app.post('/userdashboard', userData);
app.get('/getdata', getdata);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Dashboard Backend listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

This is my modelschema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const PhotoSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        trim:true,
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        trim:true,
        required:true
    },
    photo:{
        data:Buffer,
        contentType:String
    },
    mno:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    }

  });

  module.exports=mongoose.model('photo',PhotoSchema);
```

Comment: I am sorry yeah there is no else statement there is try catch in my getdata part and the problem is in try part there is the code which find the data from the database and send the reponse to json.But the problem is it can not find the data by targeting its id.

Answer (score 0):

First mistake you did was not adding `console.error(error)`, if you did it would have shown exact error message.
In this case `req.photo` is `undefined` and you are trying to access `id` property of `undefined` which causes error to be thrown.

```
const getdata = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { photo } = req.body

    // TODO: use custom error class for validation errors instead of default Error class
    if (!photo) throw new Error('photo is missing')
    if (!photo.id) throw new Error('photo.id is missing')
    // TODO: validate photo.id is valid monogoid 
    
    const photos = await photo.find({ photo: photo.id })
    res.json(photos)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error) // <-- this was missing
    res.status(400).json({ error: 'not find' }) // provide good error message
    return
  }
}
```